# Cannot run web page in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to vscode.

My Problem may seem stupid.

I have 3 files: `index.html`, `index.js` and `index.css`.

i have the chrome debugging extension installed and cant figure out how to run my code

If i want to run / debug i am getting this error in chrome

[image: chrome ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

i am sure problem is with the launch.json file. Here it is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

what i want is the index.html to be launched

Comment: no, it is just static web page

Comment: use python SimpleHTTPServer to serve static content from a directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you aren't running any webserver for it to look on localhost, you can't set the url to `localhost` but rather simply tell chrome to open the file from your workspace.

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html", // <-- This should be the path of the index.html file relative to the workspace
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```